# Can you disable fullscreen editing in landscape in React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

In an `EditText` Android element you can prevent the "fullscreen editing mode" from activating in landscape with `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` (as detailed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Flags)).

Is there any way to replicate the same behavior with a React Native `TextInput` component? I've searched through the docs and StackOverflow and have not found a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Starting from v0.40.0 React Native's `TextInput` has the prop [`disableFullscreenUI`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#disablefullscreenui), which sets `imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` internally.

`<TextInput disableFullscreenUI={true} />`

Answer (score 4):

One solution would be to write a custom native component and bind it to your React Native project. You would basically create a custom `EditText` that either has imeOptions set by default to `android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"` or for a more dynamic behavior you can create a setter in your custom EditText and expose it using `@ReactProp`. This way you would be able to set it through the component's props from your React Native project.

Writing a custom UI component (especially a simple one like this) is pretty straight forward and **much** easier than it may sound. There's a decent [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html) and plenty of tutorials out there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Accepting because it seems like that's probably the only way to do that currently. I'll give it a shot and if I get it to work I'll post a link to the component here for others to use.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this via `setNativeProps`? Does that even exist on Android?

Comment: @MattFoley Using `setNativeProps` on a React Native component (`Text`) doesn't mean that you can access properties of the native component (`TextView`) that are not exposed to the React Native one. As the documentation states, you use `setNativeProps` *to make changes directly to a component without using state/props to trigger a re-render of the entire subtree*. If a property of a native component is not available in React Native you can't access it unless you create your own custom native component and bind it to React Native.